# How to change the timestamp format in Postgresql to extract day part of the str?

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, datetime

I have create a datetime with type timestamp. **datetime timestamp NOT NULL** I am not sure why the output is like this:
[image]

I want to extract the day part. I have tried these different approach but in both cases I am getting an error. How can I fix it?

```
extract(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP min(to_char(u.datetime ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'))::timestamp)

EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP min(to_char(u.datetime ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')))

 date_part('day', min(to_char(u.datetime ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')))
```

As mentioned in response I modified query to be like below and it does work.

```
extract(day from MIN(datetime)) as Day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
select *, extract(day from activated_at) as Day from yourTable;
```

What you are seeing is a timestamp formatted as text for the display. Underlying data is timestamp as you said, directly use it.